# How to expose my angular 4 to internet using ngrok?

Tags: node.js, angular, ngrok

i have an angular app running on localhost with port 80, when i use **ngrok http 80** command it shows invalid host header. how to use ngrok to work with my angular 4?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

if your local angular webapp runs at port 80, run:

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 80
```

Note: ngrok should be added to your PATH

Comment: first load is really slow or its in my case only?

Comment: Yes, it's very slow

Answer (score 11):

I have managed to to solve this by running my angular app like this `ng serve --disable-host-check` this should work for you